# Cannot Filter List View with Yes/No Values

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, calculated-column, modern-experience

I am trying to create two different views for work anniversary and birthdays to only show if the current month is the same as hire date and birth date.

I have the following calculated column, which returns a Yes/No value: (the column is called `BirthdayThisMonth`)

```
=IF(MONTH(NOW())=MONTH([Birth Date]),"Yes","No")
```

It works as intended which is good, the issue is when I go to create a new list view, I set the filter to: `BirthdayThisMonth` is equal to Yes, and I load the view but nothing populates?

There are list items that contain Yes values but they are not showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the same steps as given below & it works for me:

1. Create a calculated column with formula (with return type as **Single line of text**).

```
=IF(MONTH(NOW()) = MONTH([DateField]), "Yes", "No")
```

Where `DateField` is my date column.

[image]

2. Edited existing view with below filters:

[image]

**Original list (All items)**:

[image]

**Output - Filter list view**:

[image]

---

**Note**:

1. Make sure there are no trailing spaces (before/after) `Yes` in filter condition & it is exactly matching to calculated column value.
2. Hard refresh (Ctrl + F5) after saving list view settings OR try clearing browser cache.

Comment: My Calculated column is identical, and there are no trailing spaces this is copied and pasted from the condition: `=IF(MONTH(NOW())=MONTH([DateField]),"Yes","No")`. My filter condition is identical to yours as well with no trailing spaces. I set the view, hard refresh, and I get the following in the list view: There are no items to show in this view of the "Birthday" list.

Comment: Your data type is set to Yes/No correct?

Comment: No. **Single line of text**. Sorry, I forgot to mention. updated my answer with calculated column details.

Comment: Problem solved. Many thanks!